# Magento2: Media image type attribue not visible in product add/edit section

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.1, media

I have created a Media image type product attribute section and assign this attribute in default attribute set.

But attribute not visible in product add/edit section.

Attribute created:
[image]

Assigned in default attribute set:-
[image]

Not visible in product add/edit section:-
[image]

Please help me how to use media type product attribute in magento2.

Comment: create attribute using script or admin ??

Comment: I have created the attribute Using admin

Answer (score 1):

The type media image isn't an uploader for special images. It's a role like "small image" in the "Images and Videos" section.